# How to represent a unweight directed graph and find the shortest path? Java

Tags: java, graph

What is the best way to represent graph in Java ? I did it in this way:

```
public class Node<T> {
public T data;
public LinkedList<Node> children;
public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<Node>(); //here there are the connected nodes of the node
}

public T getData() {
    return this.data;
}
public void addArch(Node n) {
    children.add(n);
}


public class Graph <T> {
private Node<T> source = new Node(null);
private Node<T> target = new Node(null);
private ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

public Graph() {}
public void addNode(T v) {
    boolean visto = false;
    for (Node n: nodes) {
        if (n.getData().equals(v)) {
            visto = true;
        }
    }
    if (visto == false) {
        nodes.add(new Node(v));
    }
}
public void addEdge(T p, T a) throws NoSuchNodeException {
    boolean visto = false;
    boolean visto_secondo = false;
    for (Node n: nodes) {
        if (n.getData().equals(p)) {
            visto = true;
        }
    }
    for (Node n: nodes) {
        if (n.getData().equals(a)) {
            visto_secondo = true;
        }
    }
    if (visto == false || visto_secondo == false) {
        throw new NoSuchNodeException();
    }
    else {
        for (Node n : nodes) {
            if (p.equals(n.getData())) {
                System.out.print(a);

                n.addArch(new Node(a));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have to find the shortest path but it seems like the archs are not added,why ? I did also the set and get of source and target. However I have to find the shortest path between this source and target,what is the algorithm to use? I need to use a bfs to get the shortest path but my problem is how to iterate over archs,I need to do a recursive function I think

Comment: I don't think so,because I don't know how to do a recursive function that explore the children,it seems like that the archs are not added. I have to implement it in Node class but when I do source.recursivefunction() it doesn't explore nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The best algorithm for finding the shortest path to a goal node is [Iterative Deepening A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*).

It finds the shortest path to the goal node provided the heuristic value is admissible, meaning it doesn't overestimate.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
 node              current node
 g                 the cost to reach current node
 f                 estimated cost of the cheapest path (root..node..goal)
 h(node)           estimated cost of the cheapest path (node..goal)
 cost(node, succ)  step cost function
 is_goal(node)     goal test
 successors(node)  node expanding function, expand nodes ordered by g + h(node)

 procedure ida_star(root)
   bound := h(root)
   loop
     t := search(root, 0, bound)
     if t = FOUND then return bound
     if t = ∞ then return NOT_FOUND
     bound := t
   end loop
 end procedure

 function search(node, g, bound)
   f := g + h(node)
   if f > bound then return f
   if is_goal(node) then return FOUND
   min := ∞
   for succ in successors(node) do
     t := search(succ, g + cost(node, succ), bound)
     if t = FOUND then return FOUND
     if t < min then min := t
   end for
   return min
 end function
```

The g represents the number of moves to get to the current state and h represents the estimated number of moves to get to the goal state. `f := g + h(node)`. The closer the heuristic value is to the actual number of moves, the faster the algorithm

Comment: Thank you for the reply,but I used the same code as my question but fixed: https://bitbucket.org/Klinda/network/src